# lnk2001 error in VS trying to use the Bullet physics library

Tags: c++, static-linking, bullet, lnk2001

I'm new to C++, Visual Studio (2019) and Bullet (2.89).
I've been tying to build the Hello_World.cpp from Bullet for the past few days but I'm stuck on these 5 linking errors:

```
1>Hello_World.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall btCollisionShape::getBoundingSphere(class btVector3 &,float &)const " (?getBoundingSphere@btCollisionShape@@UBEXAAVbtVector3@@AAM@Z)
1>Hello_World.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual float __thiscall btCollisionShape::getAngularMotionDisc(void)const " (?getAngularMotionDisc@btCollisionShape@@UBEMXZ)
1>Hello_World.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual float __thiscall btCollisionShape::getContactBreakingThreshold(float)const " (?getContactBreakingThreshold@btCollisionShape@@UBEMM@Z)
1>Hello_World.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall btConvexShape::project(class btTransform const &,class btVector3 const &,float &,float &,class btVector3 &,class btVector3 &)const " (?project@btConvexShape@@UBEXABVbtTransform@@ABVbtVector3@@AAM2AAV3@3@Z)
1>Hello_World.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall btSphereShape::calculateLocalInertia(float,class btVector3 &)const " (?calculateLocalInertia@btSphereShape@@UBEXMAAVbtVector3@@@Z)
```

There are other people who had this or a similar problem but got no answer or it didn't work for me.

setup:

- I used premake to set up the VS solution, Bullet is organized in static Libraries (as projects with source code that gets compiled to lib files) and I am now trying to link them with an application-project.
- all projects are using static linking (for debug).
- I've referenced all bullet projects to my project.
- I've even staticly linked to the lib files from bullet (and the linker can apparently see these files, I even tried giving the absolute path)
- As far as I can tell the functions exist and have the same signature in the .cpp and .h files

If you need more details let me know.

(One lead I possibly got is something about different bt_double_precision? But that might not be it and the only think I could find was floating point model using different precision. But making that the same didn't do anything)

Thanks in advance!

*EDIT:*
I don't think this answer applies to me

[What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

*EDIT:*
Maybe worth mentioning: The file structure of the project is really weird (dictated by premake):

- solution and project files are in:  bullet3-2.89\build3\vs2010
- high level header files(these are the ones used by Hello_World that include other headers): bullet3-2.89\src
- source and header files are subdirectories of bullet3-2.89\src
- libraries: bullet3-2.89\bin
  but all headers use the correct relative paths in their include and I have set the project's include and library directories to those locations

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Are these five functions the only ones that cannot be found, or are there more?

Comment: All five of these are declared as `const`. But maybe the library was built with them not being `const`. Try to remove `const` from header files and see what happens. Undo the changes, if they don't solve the problem.

Comment: @Dialecticus these are the only ones for Hello_World.cpp but maybe there would be more if I called more functions from Bullet

Comment: @Dialecticus I compiled the library from the source files to begin with and the const matches in source and header files

Comment: @RichardCritten going through the list there is nothing that occurs to me as plausible

Comment: I think you would be better served if you ask this question in [Bullet forum](https://pybullet.org/Bullet/phpBB3/viewforum.php?f=9).

Comment: @Dialecticus good idea, did that now https://pybullet.org/Bullet/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=12944

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue where just a few of the functions didn't link.

This is most likely due to the Bullet library being built with `BT_USE_DOUBLE_PRECISION`, meaning all `btScaler` will be of type double.

But the library is included without `BT_USE_DOUBLE_PRECISION`, meaning the program will try to link with the float versions of the functions.
But they don't exists since the built version uses doubles.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. Just gonna hijack one of the example projects from Bullet and use that instead. They seem to be better at VS settings than me :D
Anyway, thanks for your suggestions.